# Has anybody found a way to make Tensorboard password-protected?

Tags: tensorflow, authentication, passwords, password-protection, tensorboard

I have been trying to make the [Tensoboard](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard) password-protected, but it isn't easy as it is not a Flask app. An [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/92) has been opened last year, but no news since.

Comment: As a workaround, you can set --host parameter to 127.0.0.1 and then protect the local port with a basic authentication using nginx or something..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Tensorboard unfortunately does not have password-protection built-in, I used an nginx server within a docker container that acts as a reverse proxy.

Tensorboard is then protected with HTTP basic auth.

**nginx.conf**

```
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
  server {
    listen 5000;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:5000;
      auth_basic "Restricted Remote";
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
  }
}
```

To generate the .htpasswd file use the following command:

```
htpasswd -c .htpasswd admin
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx_reverse_proxy
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./.htpasswd:/etc/nginx/.htpasswd
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

To run use `docker-compose up -d`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog post where I explain how to create your own **sharable Tensorboards** **with authentication** on GCP in a cost-effective way. This post includes the **Terraform setup** so that the solution can be replicated with ease.

https://blog.ml6.eu/a-vertex-ai-tensorboard-alternative-for-smaller-budgets-part-2-923953c1e422

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31100166)